# Definition of a server

Tags: sql-server

Slightly random one which has been bugging me for a while.
I am confused as to what actually makes a server a sever. I understand that a web-sever like Apache 'serves' web pages to the client. Why then is an SQL database server also called as such. What behaviours do the two entities have in common that make both of them servers? Or is it simply a case of same word - different meaning.
Appreciate any light shedding
Thanks

Comment: I suspect this would be better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: sql server serves data.

Comment: A "server" serves stuff, whatever that is (might even by beer in a pub). So the word is used in many contexts of different granularity.

Comment: [Client–server model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client–server_model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear Why we used "server" keyword in general scenario.

Server means, it serve the service.

So this keyword is associate because both are given service.

Sqlserver :- it store the actual data and give response as data to application response, comes from application which is hosted on application server. In sqlserver we can get/set the from various way like direct query of select/insert/update, via stored procedure, via application , used for SSIS, SSRS, SSAS services too.

Apache web server :- It is Web server, means a location where your application is actually hosted. It is used "WEB" keyword means it is used for web technologies and web application is hosted on that.

Both are different in terms of service, but give service or response as request comes, that why we called server.

Answer (score 0):

An apache web server "serves" web pages to the client. An SQL database server "serves" databases to client applications. Applications need databases to store and extract data from, and a server provides them with exactly that.

Comment: So a server is simply something which provides a resource or service.
Clear now.
Thanks